# Material-UI Theme doesn't work for props.children

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am trying to use [React Composition/Containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) for my modal. Everything works fine, except **Material-ui Theme**.

I'm trying to create a Component `Modal`

```
const Modal = (props) => {
    return (
       <Box>
          {props.children}
       </Box>
    );
}
```

where i can write custom content as a children like.

```
<Modal>
   <Typography color="textPrimary">Some text here</Typography>
</Modal>
```

The problem is here that it looks like Material-ui Theme doesn't reach everything inside `{props.children}`. So `textPrimary` from my theme doesn't assign to `Typography` below. Its color somehow remains the **default value** and **doesn't get the value from Theme**.
I've tried to use theme hooks `useTheme()`, also wrap it with `ThemeProvider`, nothing worked.

My `App.js`

```
import defaultTheme from "../themes/default-theme";
import darkTheme from "../themes/dark-theme";
...
const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        ...
    },
    palette: createPalette({
        ...
        text: {
            primary: "#1C242C",
            secondary: "#5B7083",
        }
    }),
});

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
                <Switch>
                    ...
                    <Route path="/topic" component={TopicPage} />
                    ...
                </Switch>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

My `Modal` component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Box, IconButton, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";
...

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    ...
}));

function CrudModal(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <MuiModal open={true}>
            <Fade in={true}>
                <Box className={classes.paper}>
                    <Box className={classes.header}>
                        ...
                    </Box>
                    <Box>
                        {props.children}
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Fade>
        </MuiModal>
    );
}
```

Component that uses `Modal`:

```
import {Box, Button, MuiThemeProvider, TextField, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";
...

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    ...
});

const TestSection = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    ...

    return (
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" mt={5} py={2}>
            <Box display="flex">
            ...

            <CrudModal>
                <Box px={3} pt={2}>
                    <Typography color="textPrimary">Введите название</Typography>
                </Box>
            </CrudModal>
        </Box>

    );

}

export default TestSection;
```

Comment: Do you really need to use createPalette? why not just palette: { text: { primary: '#1C242C' } } }

Comment: @PeterBartels I don't know why, but it worked. Thank you!